# How do I use java a try/catch to stop a zero division error?

Tags: java

How do I use a try/catch to stop a Zero Division error on this code.I have two files Main.java and Calculator.java can someone explain to me how I would use a try/catch to prevent a zero division this is what I am talking about. When I enter first number as 4 and divide by zero I get this error. How do I prvent this if there is another way please list bellow.

***Error***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.company.Calculator.menu(Calculator.java:46)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

***Calculator.java***

```java
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void menu(){
        int a,b;
        boolean quit=false;
        while(!quit){
            System.out.println("choose 1 for addition \n"+"" +
                    "choose 2 for subtraction\n"+
                     "choose 3 for multiplication \n"+
                    "choose 4 for division \n" +
                    "choose 5 to quit");
            int menuitem=sc.nextInt();


            switch (menuitem) {
                case 1 -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number.");
                    a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number ");
                    b = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(a + b);
                }
                case 2 -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number");
                    a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number");
                    b = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(a - b);
                }
                case 3 -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number");
                    a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number");
                    b = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(a * b);
                }
                case 4 -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number");
                    a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number");
                    b = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(a / b);
                }
                case 5 -> {
                    quit = true;
                    System.out.println("Quiting...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Main.java***

```java
package com.company;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.menu();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `try/catch` for this simple error, just check the divisor in an `if` within the `case` for division operation.

Answer (score 2):

Since we don't want it to be divided by zero, in your division section, add check for it:

```
case 4 -> {
    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    b = sc.nextInt();
    if(b != 0){
      System.out.println(a / b);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Cannot divide by zero. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    calc.menu();
} catch (ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.println("dividend cannot be zero");
}
```

Comment: I would reduce the scope of the try so that you can be sure it is thrown for the reason your error message assumes.

Answer (score -1):

```
case 4 -> {
                    System.out.println("Enter first number");
                    a = sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second number");
                    b = sc.nextInt();
                    try{
                         System.out.println(a / b);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                           System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It should be avoided to catch unspecific exceptions, especially if it is a very specific one

Comment: so you should get try catch all over switch case

Comment: no, just change it to ArithmeticException, but I guess in your specific case it doesn’t change much

Comment: this is an general error nothing can be divide by 0 so any how it will be given an error what try catch do is that it does not force stop your program